# What would be the simplest and cutting edge network configuration?

Tags: linux, networking, dns

I'm trying to better understand how network services are organized and work together. Recently I moved from Ubuntu to Manjaro.  There (on Ubuntu) `systemd-resolved` is used for DNS resolution managment. In Manjaro 20 it's disabled by default.

I found this topic https://forum.manjaro.org/t/etc-resolv-conf-doesnt-update-dns-after-openvpn/116056 where suggested to disable NetworkManager at all. Is it good idea?

If I stop NetworkManager gui stops showing networks, but network actually available and works fine. In Ubuntu e.g. stopping NM leads to connection drop.

I read manuals couple of days e.g. these among others and still have no clear understanding how things are made.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/DNS

There  systemd-resolved, systemd-networkd, dnsmasq, NetworkManager, resolvconf, netplan (new for Ubuntu, it looks simple to use). I would like to know how these are interconnected? Could anyone help me with this, links or whatever you find applicable?

One of the reason this question appeared because I setup VPN and encountered DNS leaks due to NetworkManager overwrites `/etc/resolv.conf` pushed from VPN server options and setup via `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf`. I added `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/my.conf` containing following.

```
[main]
dns=none
```

After that everything looks fine. So as I understand from `man resolv.conf` is that this is the DNS server list and the services (like NM) I mentioned above just manage it defining different rules, e.g. replacing with symlinks to own files and etc.?

Also it's confusing that `man resolvconf` tells that for now it's actually symlinked to `resolvectl`, but `file /usr/bin/resolvconf` gives this.

```
/usr/bin/resolvconf: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

**So what would be the "right" most simple and modern configuration?** Explanation on these are also wanted.

I am not looking for a high-level overview. Rather, I want to know how these components are interacting, conflicting, or avoiding conflicts.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for simple code/architecture or simple administration? These are somewhat at odds here.

Comment: I would like to know what system components and it's configuration would be most relevant for using. E.g. whether to use NetworkManager with systemd-resolved or canonical resolvconf. Or systemd-resolved in couple with systemd-networkd. I would like to know pros and cons for these.